# Term for both utopias and dystopias?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I am writing a comparative analysis paper of *Walden Two* and *Brave New World* from a political theory perspective. What I was wondering is if there is a term for these kinds of work which bridges the negative/positive divide? In other words, utopia doesn't describe BNW, and dystopia doesn't describe W2, yet I need a term which describes both books.

Any literature analysis folks have suggestions or know what the commonly used term for this kind of work is?

Comment: I just made a quick google search but I found that latin word "topia" can be used or "landscape".  Also there is this website explains more http://www.affixes.org/t/-topia.html   Maybe you can mentioned it in a sentence something like this: They dream living in some kind of weird topia in their heads. Not good not bad, just their place that they imagine.

Comment: Make a big deal of the fact that the *u* in *utopia* is not the opposite of *dys* in *dystopia*.  Then adopt *utopia* as your general term and coin *eutopia* for the antonym of *dystopia*.  Make sure the rest of your paper makes no sense, and you'll have the literature analysis folks declaring you a genius.

Comment: Possibly: Negative Utopia, or Positive Dystopia, Cracked Utopia, Dolustopia (Latin *dolus* = deceitful)

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker of North American English, I would likely call them [Alternative Societies.](http://www.utopianfiction.com/m/index.html)

[Speculative Fiction](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/speculative-fiction) would be appropriate as well, and the term is now widely understood, though usually in a broader context.